# Trigonometry - how to find angles of triangle within another triangle?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image]

What are the angles of angle 1 and 2?

I don't see how any of them could be corresponding angles...

The adjacent side of angle 2 is parallel to the hypotenuse of the bigger triangle, just to make it clear.

Comment: Is that smaller triangle a right trangle (i.e. the third angle is $90^\circ$)?

Comment: Yes. Hypotenuse of the smaller triangle points straight downwards, then the adjacent side to the 2nd angle is parallel to the hypotenuse of the big triangle, the remaining side (the "right" side of the smaller triangle is perpendicular to the hypotenuse of the big triangle).

Comment: Then one of your postulates from geometry will assert that Angle 1 is $20^\circ$, as the adjacent side to Angle 2 and the hypotenuse of the bigger triangle are parallel lines. Since also the smaller triangle is a right triangle, what can you say now about Angle 2?

Comment: well, I know that both angle 1 and 2 should add up to 90∘. But I don't see how angle 1 should be 20∘... Care to elaborate or give link to a similar case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a picture that will hopefully explain why Angle 1 is $20^\circ$.

[image]

If you solve for $\angle 1$ from the equation $$70^\circ + \angle 1 + 90^\circ = 180^\circ,$$ you will find that $\angle 1 = 20^\circ$.

Comment: So I kinda wonder, what would that angle be? http://i.imgur.com/hMyJIlW.png

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Given:$\angle A=20, \angle ACB=90, \angle EBD=90$

$\angle ABC+\angle CBD +\angle EBD=180\Rightarrow 70+\angle CBD+90=180 \Rightarrow \angle CBD=20$

Given:$\angle BDC=90 \Rightarrow \angle BCD+\angle CDB+\angle CBD=180$(sum of 3 angles of triangle=180)

$\therefore \angle BCD=70$